# Unexpected behavior of a variable in a class

Tags: c#, class, variables

I have a system timer firing an event every 10 seconds. So every 10 seconds I call the class "Termocoppia" from the main thread of the form transferring the value of "milliV" to it and expecting to get back the value of variable "tempEx".

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

        public Form1()
        {
        InitializeComponent();
        System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        timer.Tick += OnTimerTick;
        timer.Interval = 10000;
        timer.Start();
}

double tempEx;

//here a call the method "Calcola" in the class "Termocoppia"
private void OnTimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        double milliV = Convert.ToDouble(textBox8.Text); //I have a value of 1.111
        Termocoppia thm = new Termocoppia();
        thm.Calcola(milliV, tempEx);
        textBox7.Text = tempEx.ToString();
}
```

the value milliV is then transferred to the method "Calcola" inside the class "Termocoppia". I debugged it with a break point and I confirm that the value is received in the class.

The class "Termocoppia" is like this:

```
public  class Termocoppia
{
    public double Calcola(double milliV,  double tempEx)//here the value of milliV is still 1.111
    {  
        tempEx= milliV;//here the value of tempEx is 0???
        return tempEx;
    }
}
```

I expect to receive back exactly the same value sent to the class that is well received but I keep getting back 0.
If I debug the variable tempEx at the line "tempEx=milliV" the value of tempEx is 0 and I do not understand why? I am quite sure I am doing a beginner mistake here but I cannot come right with this problem.

Comment: have you just debugged onto that line or over it? tempEx will be 0 until your on the next line

Comment: Keep in mind that parameters of type `double` are passed by value. `tempEx= milliV;` will NOT change your `double tempEx;` since they are two different objects. As a very simple rule assigning a value to a parameter is most often not what you want, except for `out` and `ref` parameters.

Comment: I just checked,at the line "return tempEx" the value is correct (1.111) but then if I check in private void OnTimerTick in the main form it is 0. Looks like I do not manage to get it back.

Comment: Felice, the two answers below are correct, I was just explaining why its 0 there.

Comment: @Sayse of course. I understood your intention. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two variables called 'tempEx', a field and a parameter. Your `Calcola` function modifies the `tempEx` parameter (not the field) and returns the same value. But the caller is not doing anything with the returned value. My suggestion is to two this value into the field `tempEx`.

Modify your line:

```
thm.Calcola(milliV, tempEx);
```

into:

```
tempEx = thm.Calcola(milliV, tempEx);
```

A suggestion: Use a coding standard to prevent this kind of mistakes. For parameters use camelCasing (so tempEx), for fields use an underscore (_tempEx).

Comment: This works perfectly. Thanks a lot. I new I was doing a beginner mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the return value from Termocoppia.Calcola.

```
private void OnTimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double milliV = Convert.ToDouble(textBox8.Text); //I have a value of 1.111
    Termocoppia thm = new Termocoppia();
    // the return value from Cacola has to be assigned to tempEx
    tempEx = thm.Calcola(milliV, tempEx);
    textBox7.Text = tempEx.ToString();
}
```

You should not use the same variable names for tempEx as member variable and method parameter!

Comment: Thanks, this is basically the same answer already given by Martin.